# Installing SugarCRM on AWS machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, sugarcrm

I am installing SugarCRM using sugarcrm-CE-6.4.2-linux-installer.bin file on a AWS ubuntu machine. This machine already has apache, will that instance be affected by SugarCRM intsaller?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll wind up with two instances of apache.  To get the server without its dependencies get:
http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/download
instead.  (~19 MB zip file).  But then you would have to configure your existing Apache to talk to it, and PHP MySQL etc.
Apache says by default only one instance of the Daemon runs (configurable) so that means you would wind up with whichever started latest instead of two:
http://www.jasny.net/articles/running-multiple-instances-of-apache/

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.1/-docs-Administration_Guides-CommunityEdition_Install_Admin_Guide_5.1-Sugar_Install.3.3.html

Note: I'm not an expert and could have something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If that installer also installs apache then that apache won't work as it will try to run on port 80, on which default apache might be running in, infact what you can do is change the port of already running apache to 90 or something else. So new apache if being installed with crm, will not be any problem then.